# Pointer by reference in C++

Tags: c++

I've always learned that by passing a variable by reference only means that the variable will maintain any changes made to the variable in the function and the working of the function will not change but in this case the function completely works differently.
The only difference is in the definition of this function in the two codes.
void rotate(node*&);
void rotate(node*);

THIS IS THE FIRST CODE

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    char data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node()
    {
        left=0;
        right=0;
    }
};
class AVL
{
private:
    node* root;
public:
    AVL()
    {
        root=NULL;
    }
    void initialize();
    void rotate(node*&);
    node*& return_n()
    {
        return root->left;
    }
    void traverse();

};
void AVL::initialize()
{
    root=new node;
    root->data='a';
    root->left=new node;
    root->left->data='b';
    root->left->left=new node;
    root->left->left->data='c';
    root->left->left->left=new node;
    root->left->left->left->data='d';
}
void AVL::traverse()
{
    node* temp=root;
    if(temp!=0)
    {
        stack<node*> s;
        s.push(temp);
        while(!s.empty())
        {
            temp=s.top();
            s.pop();
            cout<<endl<<temp->data<<endl;
            if(temp->left!=0)
            {
                s.push(temp->left);
                cout<<"Left: "<<s.top()->data<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Left: NULL"<<endl;
            }
            if(temp->right!=0)
            {
                s.push(temp->right);
                cout<<"Right: "<<s.top()->data<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Right: NULL ";
            }
        }
    }
}
void AVL::rotate(node*& temp)
{
    node* temp2=temp->left;
    cout<<endl<<"Step1"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp"<<temp->data<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp2"<<temp2->data<<endl;
    traverse();
    temp->left=temp2->right;
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Step2"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp"<<temp->data<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp2"<<temp2->data<<endl;
    traverse();
    temp2->right=temp;
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Step3"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp"<<temp->data<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp2"<<temp2->data<<endl;
    traverse();
    temp=temp2;
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Step4"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp"<<temp->data<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp2"<<temp2->data<<endl;
    traverse();
    system("pause");
}
int main()
{
    AVL obj;
    obj.initialize();
    obj.traverse();
    obj.rotate(obj.return_n());
    return 0;
}
```

THIS IS THE SECOND CODE

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
struct node
{
    char data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node()
    {
        left=0;
        right=0;
    }
};
class AVL
{
private:
    node* root;
public:
    AVL()
    {
        root=NULL;
    }
    void initialize();
    void rotate(node*);
    node*& return_n()
    {
        return root->left;
    }
    void traverse();

};
void AVL::initialize()
{
    root=new node;
    root->data='a';
    root->left=new node;
    root->left->data='b';
    root->left->left=new node;
    root->left->left->data='c';
    root->left->left->left=new node;
    root->left->left->left->data='d';
}
void AVL::traverse()
{
    node* temp=root;
    if(temp!=0)
    {
        stack<node*> s;
        s.push(temp);
        while(!s.empty())
        {
            temp=s.top();
            s.pop();
            cout<<endl<<temp->data<<endl;
            if(temp->left!=0)
            {
                s.push(temp->left);
                cout<<"Left: "<<s.top()->data<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Left: NULL"<<endl;
            }
            if(temp->right!=0)
            {
                s.push(temp->right);
                cout<<"Right: "<<s.top()->data<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Right: NULL ";
            }
        }
    }
}
void AVL::rotate(node* temp)
{
    node* temp2=temp->left;
    cout<<endl<<"Step1"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp"<<temp->data<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp2"<<temp2->data<<endl;
    traverse();
    temp->left=temp2->right;
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Step2"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp"<<temp->data<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp2"<<temp2->data<<endl;
    traverse();
    temp2->right=temp;
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Step3"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp"<<temp->data<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp2"<<temp2->data<<endl;
    traverse();
    temp=temp2;
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Step4"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp"<<temp->data<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Temp2"<<temp2->data<<endl;
    traverse();
    system("pause");
}
int main()
{
    AVL obj;
    obj.initialize();
    obj.traverse();
    obj.rotate(obj.return_n());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please remove irrelevant code

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking in this question. Please clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Your question is missing important details. Describe how the two functions *completely works differently*. How does one behave? How does the other behave? What is the difference? What is the expected or intended behaviour?

Comment: Not sure what you want, but a ref is pointer is `*&` backwards I know.

Answer (score 2):

By passing `obj.return_n()` by reference, you give the function the possibility to modify this reference.

In the first code, when you encounter those lines:

```
temp=temp2;
cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;
cout<<endl<<"Step4"<<endl;
cout<<endl<<"Temp"<<temp->data<<endl;
cout<<endl<<"Temp2"<<temp2->data<<endl;
traverse();
```

`temp` is a reference to `root->left` which is used in `AVL::traverse()`, and is modified before the call to `traverse()`. In the second case, `temp` being a copy, `root->left` is **not** modified, then `traverse` does not behave as if it had been.

Hence the difference.

You should learn to use references properly. You can prevent them from being modified with the **const** keyword. I would add that references to pointers looks like a poor design.

Answer (score 2):

Too much code for a simple question of passing pointer by reference. When you pass pointer by reference, the pointer itself can be modified in the function and the change will be preserved. When pointer passed is passed by value, modification to the the pointer will be lost, but any object modified through that pointer will remain modified. Simple example:

```
int glob_x;
int glob_y;

void modify_ptr(int*& ptr) {
    ptr = &glob_x;
}

void modify_value(int* ptr) {
   *ptr = 42;
   ptr = &glob_y;
}

int main() {
  int* p;
  modify_ptr(p); // after this line p points to glob_x
  modify_value(p); // now glob_x is 42, but p is still pointing to glob_x
  *p = 56; // glob_x is now 56
}
```